# Meaning of "I have three books and CDs"

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, ambiguity, numbers

> I have three books and CDs.

Does this mean I have three books and three CDs? Or are there three items in total? Are both possible?

I am asking for a native speaker's opinion.

Comment: Two variants are possible: 3 books \ 3 CDs, 3 books \ some CDs. They are not 3 in total, since these are two different things and we don't count them like this (2+1? 1+2?)

Comment: But 40 kids and adults means 40 in total. As is obvious from this site, http://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/real-life/the-case-of-incest-and-depravity-which-came-to-rest-in-the-hills-of-a-quiet-country-town/story-fnixwvgh-1226780575248

Comment: @Vilmar I disagree. It doesn't work well with 3, so imagine 8. The line could absolutely mean 8 books + some number of CDs or 8 books and CDs in total. What it *doesn't* mean is that you have 8 CDs.

Comment: @kih1930 That's why I made a remark about them being too different - in your example these concepts are close - kids, adults = people, so we could rephrase it as "40 people were...". In the first example we can't do this unless we generalize a lot (items). I'm not saying it's totally incorrect, but I wouldn't catch this meaning on the go without context.

Comment: Context is everything. This is not the only phrase in English, or really any language, that is ambiguous on its own. Ambiguity is the rule, not an exception. Without enough context, this question is unanswerable. And with enough context, it would not exist because the answer would be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you want to divide the phrases in the sentence:

> 1) I've got [3 books] and CDs.

This means you have 3 books, and some CDs.

> 2) I have 3 [books and CDs].

This version is more clunky, but it means you have 3 in total. Unless, however, "*books and CDs*" is referring to a specific single item meaning one book and one CD per item, which would then mean three of each.

When I read this sentence, my brain opted for the first version. I would consider cleaning up the ambiguity like so:

> 1) I have 3 books, and some CDs.
>
> 2) I have 2 books, and a CD. **OR** I have a book, and 2 CDs.

If you're dealing with larger numbers, a catch-all approach to *2.* could be:

> 2) I have a collection of books and CDs, there are 3 in total.

Comment: So both my interpretations are possible, you say?

Comment: Yes, but the second is less likely to be interpreted because its ambiguous, and the reader is most likely to take the least ambiguous reading on the first parse.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. But I see so many sentences like this. So I am always confused.

Answer (score 1):

You either have three books and an indeterminate number of CDs or you have 3 total of both. It would be clearer to reword the phrase. What it absolutely does *not* suggest is that you have 3 CDs.

Comment: downvoter is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The meaning depends on the context.

If someone asked, "How many books do you have and how many CDs?", then, this answer would mean that they have three books *and* three CDs.

However, if someone asked, "What do you have there?", then this answer would be ambiguous and could mean three books and three CDs, or three books and *some* CDs. I would interpret it as three books and three CDs, but I don't know about others.

As to the question of whether there are three in total, that could also be. I asked a colleague out of the blue what he would understand from this statement and he answered that it meant that I had a total of three books and CDs. So both are possible.

I suggest you avoid this wording and explicitly state the numbers.

Comment: I'm sorry, it would be very poor English for the line to be interpreted as 3 CDs. It is ambiguous, but the ambiguity is only between 3+n or x+y=3. 3 CDs is not one of the options of interpretation.

Comment: I did not mean *just* 3 CDs. I meant *3 books and 3 CDs*. Look at it this way, one might want to truncate their response and hence, decide to use the number just once, considering that the two are different objects and wouldn't be clubbed together anyway.

Comment: Total means x+y=3. That is one of the 2 (and only 2) options allowed by the phrase in the OP. "3 books and 3 CDs" is a much better line because it removes the ambiguity of the line in the OP.